# what might be possible reasons in Informix enterprise replication to fails after first record replicated?

Tags: informix, database-replication

I have two ubuntu  servers where enterprise replication configured, I have create 2 sample table with only one column with primary key & I defined replication for those tables. In each table first record replication was successful. But I tried inserting another record but it is failing in both tables & following errors are indicated in log file( I'm inserting unique value each time).

CDR CDRDS: transaction aborted (Error return from SQL for the commit command) with sql error 268 isam error 100.
06:46:51  CDR CDRDS: transaction aborted (Error return from SQL for the commit command) with sql error 268 isam error 100.
06:46:51  CDR CDRDS: transaction aborted (Error return from SQL for the commit command) with sql error 268 isam error 100.

Comment: Error `-268` is `Unique constraint <constraint-name> violated.` and error `-100` is `ISAM error: duplicate value for a record with unique key.` so it seems you are trying to insert a duplicate in your primary key column.

Comment: No I was trying unique values only. I have resolved it by using --erkey while defining replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use --erkey in Informix replication command